# Twitter API 1.1 Tweets

Tags: php, twitter

Hello after twitter has updated it's API to 1.1 I am facing a very serious problem. You can see a lot of it has changed. For example look at my code it does not work any more after twitter API has been updated.

```
<?php
$content = "";
if (!isset($username)){
    $username = "Hassan_Tech";
}
if (!isset($number)){
    $number = 5;
}

$url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name={$username}&count={$number}";
$tweets = file_get_contents($url);
$feed = new SimpleXMLElement($tweets);

function time_stamp($date){
    if (empty($date)){
        return "No date provided";
    }
    $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
    $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");
    $now = time();
    $unix_date = strtotime($date);
    if (empty($unix_date)){
        return "Bad date";
    }
    if ($now > $unix_date){
        $difference = $now - $unix_date;
        $tense = "ago";
    } else {
        $difference = $unix_date - $now;
        $tense = "from now";
    }
    for ($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++){
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
    }
    $difference = round($difference);
    if ($difference != 1){
        $periods[$j] .= "s";
    }
    return "$difference $periods[$j] $tense";
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= $number-1; $i++){
    $status = $feed->status[$i];

    if (isset($status->id)){
        $id = $status->id;
    }

    $created_at = $status->created_at;
    $text = $status->text;
    $text = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\n\r\t< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ \"\t\n\r< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $text);

    if (preg_match("/#(\w+)/", $text, $matches)){
        foreach($matches as $match){
            $match = str_replace("#", "", $match);
            $text = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/","<a href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q={$match}\">$0</a>",$text);
            $text = str_replace("<a href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q={$match}\">#","<span class=\"hash\">#</span><a href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q={$match}\" target=\"_blank\">",$text);
        }
    }

    if (preg_match("/@(\w+)/", $text, $matches)) {
        foreach($matches as $match) {
            $match = str_replace("@", "", $match);
            $text = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/{$match}\">$0</a>", $text);
            $text = str_replace("<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/{$match}\">@", "<span class=\"at\">@</span><a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/{$match}\" target=\"_blank\">", $text);
        }
    }

    $content .= "<div class=\"status\"><div class=\"text\">{$text}</div>";

    if (isset($id)){
        $content .= "<div class=\"date\"><a href=\"http://twitter.com/Hassan_Tech/status/{$id}\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"".date("g:i A M jS", strtotime($created_at))."\">".time_stamp($created_at)."</a></div>";
    } else {
        $content .= "<div class=\"date\"><a href=\"\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"".date("g:i A M jS", strtotime($created_at))."\">".time_stamp($created_at)."</a></div>";
    }
    $content .= "</div>";
}

echo $content;
?>
```

Could you please help me fix this? I would really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: What is your concrete question/problem? "does not work" is a bit too broad

Comment: It does not display the tweets any more. This one is coded for API v1. Now twitter has updated it's API to v1.1 and so it does not display tweets.

Answer (score 0):

first you must to create a twitter application, you can login with your twitter credentials
https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new

then click the buton "create my access token" and copy the following codes of your twitter app:

- Consumer key
- Consumer secret
- Access token
- Access token secret

then download OAuth.php and twitteroauth.php from this github repository, and put these files in your php script folder
https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/tree/master/twitteroauth

finally you can use this code, i commented the deprecated code

```
<?php

require_once('twitteroauth.php');


define('CONSUMER_KEY', '');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', '');
define('OAUTH_TOKEN', '');
define('OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET', '');

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);


$content = "";
if (!isset($username)){
    $username = "Hassan_Tech";
}
if (!isset($number)){
    $number = 5;
}

$feed = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => $username, 'count' => $number));

//$url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name={$username}&count={$number}";
//$tweets = file_get_contents($url);
//$feed = new SimpleXMLElement($tweets);

function time_stamp($date){
    if (empty($date)){
        return "No date provided";
    }
    $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
    $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");
    $now = time();
    $unix_date = strtotime($date);
    if (empty($unix_date)){
        return "Bad date";
    }
    if ($now > $unix_date){
        $difference = $now - $unix_date;
        $tense = "ago";
    } else {
        $difference = $unix_date - $now;
        $tense = "from now";
    }
    for ($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++){
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
    }
    $difference = round($difference);
    if ($difference != 1){
        $periods[$j] .= "s";
    }
    return "$difference $periods[$j] $tense";
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= $number-1; $i++){
    $status = $feed[$i];
    //$status = $feed->status[$i];

    if (isset($status->id)){
        $id = $status->id;
    }

    $created_at = $status->created_at;
    $text = $status->text;
    $text = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w]+[^ \"\n\r\t< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[^ \"\t\n\r< ]*)#", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $text);

    if (preg_match("/#(\w+)/", $text, $matches)){
        foreach($matches as $match){
            $match = str_replace("#", "", $match);
            $text = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/","<a href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q={$match}\">$0</a>",$text);
            $text = str_replace("<a href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q={$match}\">#","<span class=\"hash\">#</span><a href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q={$match}\" target=\"_blank\">",$text);
        }
    }

    if (preg_match("/@(\w+)/", $text, $matches)) {
        foreach($matches as $match) {
            $match = str_replace("@", "", $match);
            $text = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/{$match}\">$0</a>", $text);
            $text = str_replace("<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/{$match}\">@", "<span class=\"at\">@</span><a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/{$match}\" target=\"_blank\">", $text);
        }
    }

    $content .= "<div class=\"status\"><div class=\"text\">{$text}</div>";

    if (isset($id)){
        $content .= "<div class=\"date\"><a href=\"http://twitter.com/Hassan_Tech/status/{$id}\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"".date("g:i A M jS", strtotime($created_at))."\">".time_stamp($created_at)."</a></div>";
    } else {
        $content .= "<div class=\"date\"><a href=\"\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"".date("g:i A M jS", strtotime($created_at))."\">".time_stamp($created_at)."</a></div>";
    }
    $content .= "</div>";
}

echo $content;
?>
```

it works for me, i hope it works for you too :)

Comment: It doesnt work for me, it says this error:

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\Documents\PHP\Projects\HassanTech\tweets.php on line 57

I tried to include it did not work :[

Comment: try it with my credentials

https://gist.github.com/miquelcamps/7859545

you can see how it works on my server and it's the same code
http://migueldev.com/twitter/

have you replaced this line
$status = $feed->status[$i];

to
$status = $feed[$i]; ?

Comment: Sorry miquel but your source doesn't work either. :[ It gives the same error when I try to include it via <?php include ?> so what should I do? if I goto tweets.php it shows the tweets but the problem starts when I try to include.

Comment: try to put an absolute path ej. tweets.php `require_once(__DIR__.'/twitteroauth.php');` twitteroauth.php `require_once(__DIR__.'/OAuth.php');` the three files tweets.php, twitteroauth.php and OAuth.php, must to be in the same folder

Comment: They are in the same folder, I am not that nooby dude, do you have skype or anything you could privately message me with?

Comment: Have a look at http://aamirafridi.com/twitter/twitter-api-1-1-using-php-and-javascript